# Try a speculative, concurrent, lock free, atomic update until abort condition matches

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency

Please let me know if you see any performance improvements, bugs, or anything you'd change and why.

```
    public static bool TrySpeculativeUpdate(ref int field, out int result,
        Func<int, int> update, Func<int, bool> shouldAbort)
    {
        SpinWait spinWait = new SpinWait();
        while (true)
        {
            int snapshot = field;
            if (shouldAbort(field))
            {
                result = 0;
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                int calc = update(snapshot);
                if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref field, calc, snapshot) == snapshot)
                {
                    result = calc;
                    return true;
                }
            }

            spinWait.SpinOnce();
        }
    }
```

Can be used like this

```
    private bool TryIncreaseCapacity(out int newCapacity)
    {
        return TrySpeculativeUpdate(ref _currentCapacity, out newCapacity,
            (currentCapacity) => currentCapacity + 1,
            (currentCapacity) => currentCapacity == _maxCapacity);
    }

    if (this.TryIncreaseCapacity(out newCapacity))
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    }
```

What I'm really trying to accomplish is the fastest thread safe version of Interlocked.Increment that will stop incrementing at a max value and I will have some way of detecting it stopped incrementing.

Comment: FYI, I tested this against locks and it's about 300%-350% faster on my machine.

Comment: Are you really going to have several threads that spend most of their time trying to increase a counter? I assume that's what your test did, but I doubt it's how your real code will behave. If that's the case, this might be a premature optimization.

Comment: Also, I *think* the read into `snapshot` should be volatile. You can use [`Volatile.Read()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712891) for that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I like the method's signature:

```
public static bool TrySpeculativeUpdate(ref int, out int, Func<int, int>, Func<int, bool>)
```

It's probably just me, but I like pushing `ref` and `out` parameters to the end of the parameters list, so I'd write it like this:

```
public static bool TrySpeculativeUpdate(Func<int, int>, Func<int, bool>, ref int, out int)
```

I'd use `var` to ease reading, and FWIW it *might* be clearer to pass `snapshot` instead of `field` to `shouldAbort`:

```
public static bool TrySpeculativeUpdate(Func<int, int> update, Func<int, bool> shouldAbort, ref int field, out int result)
{
    var spinWait = new SpinWait();
    while (true)
    {
        var snapshot = field;

        if (shouldAbort(snapshot))
        {
            result = 0;
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            var calc = update(snapshot);
            if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref field, calc, snapshot) == snapshot)
            {
                result = calc;
                return true;
            }
        }

        spinWait.SpinOnce();
    }
}
```

That's all I could see. The naming looks about right, but I don't write enough multithreaded code to know for a fact whether this code is optimal or not - it *does* look good though, I don't see how nesting could be reduced, other than by extacting a tiny little specialized function responsible for this part:

```
if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref field, calc, snapshot) == snapshot)
{
    result = calc;
    return true;
}
```

But that clearly would be overkill IMO.